# cannot read property of undefined using default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, default-value

I have a model that gets some data and filters. When the app starts I want to have all filters equal to `true`. I have set a default value but I still get the following error.

```js
const model = (data, predictions, { placeFilter = true, startDateFilter = true, endDateFilter = true }) => {
   const getData = () => data.filter(placeFilter).filter(startDateFilter).filter(endDateFilter)
}
```

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'placeFilter')
    at model (model.js:1)
    at init (index.js:15)
```

Comment: You have to name the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const model = (data, predictions, { placeFilter = true, startDateFilter = true, endDateFilter = true }) => {
   const getData = () => data.filter(placeFilter).filter(startDateFilter).filter(endDateFilter)
}
```

You cannot call the above `model` function by passing two arguments like `model([], [])` as JavaScript will try to destructure the third argument which is `undefined`.

You can do this instead:

```js
const model = (data, predictions, { placeFilter = true, startDateFilter = true, endDateFilter = true } = {}) => {
  console.log(placeFilter, startDateFilter, endDateFilter)
}

model([], [])
model([], [], { placeFilter: false })
```

---

BTW Assuming `data` is an array and you're trying to use `Array.prototype.filter`, `filter` should be called with a callback function that returns a boolean but you're directly passing booleans to all filters.

Comment: yep, the last paragraph is what I am trying to solve now

Comment: `placeFilter = () => true` this works

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter could be named to access the default value

```
const model = (data, predictions, filter = { placeFilter: true, startDateFilter: true, endDateFilter:  true }) => {
   const getData = () => data.filter(filter.placeFilter).filter(filter.startDateFilter).filter(filter.endDateFilter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const model = (data, predictions, { placeFilter = true, startDateFilter = true, endDateFilter = true } = {}) => {
  const getData = () => data.filter(placeFilter).filter(startDateFilter).filter(endDateFilter)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).